# What happens with OPENQUERY when the linked server is down/unavailable?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, linked-server, openquery

In a stored procedure on an SQL Server 2008 database, I've added an `OPENQUERY` in the `FROM` clause of a `SELECT` statement, and that in turn contains an `OPENQUERY`, something like this:

```
SELECT MyField
FROM OPENQUERY (LinkedServer, 
               'select MyField
                from OPENQUERY (OtherServer,
                                ''select t.SomeField as [MyField]
                                  from table t'');
```

Now, I wonder what happens if either one of these servers is down for some reason. Does it just return an empty result set or does it throw an error? Also, if `OtherServer` is down, do I need to handle the error in the outer `OPENQUERY`?

It is important that everything is handled within the sproc, i.e. no error should be propagated to the caller of the sproc.

The [MSDN documentation on OPENQUERY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) does not detail any behaviour in case the linked servers are unavailable.

I found [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36189) on DBA.SE that mentions the `sp_testlinkedserver` sproc. Is calling  this the way to go? How would I use it to test `OtherServer`?

Comment: Can't you simply test? Set up a pair of linked virtual machines and take one offline.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen this is in a production environment and it's not possible to just take one of the servers offline. Also, I don't have the means and the time to fiddle around with virtual machines. Apart from the query in my question, none of this is part of my job. I was just hoping someone would actually know what happens and what the best practice is in preventing unexpected results and handling any errors related to this.

Comment: I don't think that `sp_testlinkedserver` can be the correct solution because what if the second machine goes offline *part way through* processing the query? I.e. it might have already produced some result rows and sent them over the network and then **poof** the network card breaks.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever while that is theoretically possible, the chance of that seems small enough to ignore it. It is a very simple query and the servers are on the same network. If this would ever occur we'll be all right still, if this query fails there's no real harm done and we can manually recover easily. It's just that I would like some graceful error prevention/handling in place for more common cases, e.g. a server being down when the query is about to be executed.

Comment: Why is a server being down when you're just about to execute a query more likely than a server going down whilst the query is running? The point I was trying to make is that other resources on a network are independent - no amount of "pre-checking" for resources is an adequate test for "will I be able to complete the task at hand?".

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Why is it more likely? Well, suppose the query is only being run every 5 seconds (this is the actual maximum frequency at this moment). Also assume an average total execution time of 50ms (this is what it currently is). That leaves a window of 50ms for the server to go down during the query, and a window of 5 seconds for the server to go down before execution. The chance is thus only 1% for the server to go down during execution, vs. 99% before the next execution. Seems logical to me?

Answer (score 0):

We've tested it by changing credentials for `OtherServer` so that the inner `OPENQUERY` fails. An exception occurs:

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "OtherServer".
>   OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "OtherServer" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver]Access denied for user '[user]' (using password: YES)".

And it is propagated to the stored procedure. Thus, surrounding the query in a `TRY...CATCH` block should provide correct means for error handling.